# C# string array from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently using Newtonsoft's json library to deserialize json from a file.

JSON:

```
{
"name":"test", 
"description":"test",
"tags":"Maps"
}
```

C#:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
}
```

The "tags" has to be an array as it is required for steam.

How can I retrieve the "tags" as an string array?
The console prints out this expection:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "Maps" to type 'System.String[]'. Path 'tags', line 4, position 17
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json property "tags" doesn't contain an array, but just a string. Change `"Maps"` to `["Maps"]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Custom JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

```
public class StringOrArrayToStringConveter<T> : JsonConverter
```

The meat of the solution is the override of the ReadJson which you need to return an array of T.  Then you can use it like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringOrArrayToStringConveter<string>))]
public string[] tags { get; set; }
```

Hope that put you in a good starting point.

EDIT:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

  namespace ConsoleApp1
  {
      public class RootObject
      {
          public string name { get; set; }
          public string tag { get; set; }
          public string description { get; set; }
          [JsonConverter(typeof(StringOrArrayToStringConveter<string>))]
          public string[] tags { get; set; }
      }

      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              var data1 = "{\"name\":\"test\", \"description\":\"test\",\"tags\":\"Maps\"}";


              var deserialized1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data1);


              var data2 = "{\"name\":\"test\", \"description\":\"test\",\"tags\":[\"Maps\", \"Maps2\"]}";


              var deserialized2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data2);

          }
      }

      public class StringOrArrayToStringConveter<T> : JsonConverter
      {
          public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
          {
              return true;
          }

          public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
          {
              object returnValue = new Object();
              if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
              {
                  returnValue = JToken.Load(reader).ToObject<T[]>();
              }
              else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
              {
                  T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
                  returnValue = new List<T>() { instance }.ToArray();
              }
              return returnValue;
          }

          public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote but I gave a sample code that will work. Sometimes we just need to work with the data and not force to change the data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change Tag into  Dictionary e.g. public Dictionary tags { get; set; }

```
public class RootObject
 {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Tag> tags { get; set; }
 }

 public Tag
 {
   public string name{ get; set; }
 }
```